# How to pass a variable to web recorder with a specific place using automation anywhere tool?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I tried to call each data in excel and search that each data in browser and to get and save, first link matched with the searched data.so here is a doubt how to pass variable to the web recorder with a specified place using automation anywhere tool?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the Excel value on a variable: $vLinkText$ = $Excel Column(1)$

You can insert variables on Advanced View of the Web Recorder.

Example: Select Control Name then press F2 on the field.

If the control you need is not in any of the controls, enable Attributes then add the attribute.

Example:

- **Attribute:** innertext
- **Value:** $vLinkText$ *Press F2 to insert variables*

[image: Web Recorder Advanced View]